# How can virtual memory exist when there is no swap space?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ram, virtual-memory

On running the "free" command, I see that memory used is:
total:3854884
used:3752304
free:102580
shared:352
buffers:9252
cached:150908

-/+ buffers/cache:
used: 3592144
free: 262740

`Swap:            0          0          0`

But on running `htop`, I see there are many processes using 4507M amount of memory under the VIRT column (virtual memory). RES column (physical RAM the process is using) shows 209M. SHR (shared memory) is 5352M.

`-Xmx` for the process is configured as `2048m`.

How can virtual memory be used if the swap space is zero?

Comment: Would memory-mapped files be included in `VIRT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The virtual memory these programs (htop and the like) are counting is just the size of the address space the processes have requested. You have physical memory, actual RAM, and a virtual address space which maps addresses as user space programs see them to physical memory. They are separate. A `0x0ff84560` pointer probably doesn't actually reference that part of RAM. The OS gets to set up a mapping that decides where in RAM you're actually referencing. Even further, it can set up the mapping before it has RAM to back it up. It's an event driven process. The OS will set up the mapping on request with no real backing, no physical memory allocated, and only actually map it to real RAM when you try to use the virtual memory.

The size of virtual memory is the size of this mapping. But not all of it has to be backed by physical RAM, so it can be larger than RAM even when there's no swap. But this causes problems programs try to actually *use* more memory than there is RAM. It's no problem at all if they only request it, only if they use it.

Additionally, as Thilo mentioned, memory mapped files can add to this. You can map an entire 100TB file into your virtual address space no problem. The OS handles the logistics in the background: bringing in the parts you need (the parts you try to access) and reaping the parts it has to to clear physical memory.

Comment: So htop is showing me that the program requested 4GB of virtual memory but it is not going to get that anyway because of swap space being 0? That explains the crashes.

Comment: It's not only because swap space is 0. Memory mapped files make this a bit more complicated. If you memory map a 100GB file, the OS might be able to make it work, it'll just be really slow because it has to clear things out and bring new things in often, and this requires pausing your program.

Comment: It depends on what kind of virtual memory the program requested, basically.

Comment: What's special about memory mapped files is that there's a predefined place to "swap" pages out to: the file itself. With anything else (or most other things?) the OS has nowhere to store data that it needs to clear out of RAM to make room.